# m4a/mp4 file supported by IE HTML5 audio tag

Tags: html, audio, internet-explorer-9

How do I generate m4a/mp4 file with AAC audio that IE9 would support with HTML5 audio tag? I tried to generate such file with iTunes by IE9 just displays black box with red cross in place of HTML5 audio tag.

Comment: can you post a sample to check that it plays in other browsers? Also have you tried adding explicit "type" parameter to specify the MIME type and codec [see http://html5doctor.com/html5-audio-the-state-of-play/ for examples]

Comment: The same m4a file plays just fine in Chrome. I have type type="audio/mp4". I also tried replacing .m4a file with .aac file and have the same result. I want to see at least one sample HTML5 audio element with either m4a, mp4 or aac file that IE9 can successfully play.